Trying to send commands to Sony FCB-EV7520 camera
I am trying to send zoom commands, or any other commands to this camera:
Sony FCB-EV7520
I followed the instruction in their manual, tried to implement it in a python script but the non of the commands won't work.
when I go to its web page, and I use it to send the same messages for zoom in and out it works perfectly.
this is my current code:
*I hide the actual camera info
import cv2
import socket
import time

# Camera details
username = "****"
password = "****"
camera_ip = <IPADDRESS>
camera_port = <PORT>
rtsp_url = f"rtsp://{username}:{password}@{camera_ip}:8554/bandwidth_h264"

# VISCA commands
address_cmd = bytes.fromhex("88 30 01 FF")  # Set address command
if_clear_cmd = bytes.fromhex("81 01 00 01 FF")  # IF_Clear command
zoom_in_msg = bytes.fromhex("81 01 04 07 02 FF")  # Zoom in command
zoom_out_msg = bytes.fromhex("81 01 04 07 03 FF")  # Zoom out command

def send_visca_command(cmd):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
        sock.connect((camera_ip, camera_port))
        sock.sendall(cmd)
        time.sleep(0.1)  

def initialize_camera():
    # Send Address command to set the camera's address
    send_visca_command(address_cmd)
    time.sleep(1)  

    # Clear command buffers in the camera
    send_visca_command(if_clear_cmd)
    time.sleep(0.5)  

def main():
    # Initialize camera settings
    initialize_camera()

    # Open RTSP stream
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(rtsp_url)

    if not cap.isOpened():
        print("Error: could not open RTSP stream")
        return

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if not ret:
            print("Error: Failed to capture frame.")
            break

        cv2.imshow('RTSP Stream', frame)

        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if key == ord('q'):
            break
        elif key == ord('+'):
            send_visca_command(zoom_in_msg)
            print("Zoom in command sent.")
        elif key == ord('-'):
            send_visca_command(zoom_out_msg)
            print("Zoom out command sent.")

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()```


Explain "won't work". What happens, what should happen? Show an error message (if any) completely as properly formatted text in the question.

Nothing happens, I get the print of zoom send but the camera won’t respond to the messages. I don’t get any errors

Should you Not use the http API, Basic/Digest auth etc...
